# Naming conventions for set/unset method parameter

Tags: naming, clean-code, naming-standards

I have some class `MyClass` which has two methods:

```
Lock(){}
Unlock(){}
```

For some reasons, the two methods are to be unified into one, with an additional parameter for indicating the action. What should be the name of the parameter?

```
SetLockState(bool isLock)
SetLockState(bool isLocked)
// or another better name?
```

This happens a lot in our code base. I favor `isLock`, because it is the new state, but it seems there is some convention about `isLocked` which I am unfamiliar with.

I would love an explanation as to why `isLocked` is the standard. And I would like to know if there is any objective argument that can support the choice of the parameter name.

Comment: While the ultimate choice of the name is opinion-based, there are objective arguments for guiding the choice between the two alternatives, and well known objective  principles that could support the decision-making (i.e. "intention-revealing naming" promoted by clean code). This seems IMHO sufficient to consider the question as being in scope.

Comment: I font the "is" prefix confusing.  Would just use "locked" or, possible, "newLockState"

Comment: @user949300 forget the `is`. why do you think `locked` is better than `lock`?

Comment: @Gulzar "lock" would be fine.  Just don't like the leading "is" cause that implies the current, existing state.

Comment: isLocked is the naming convention for boolean methods and variables used by Sun for the Java core packages. Using the is prefix solves a common problem of choosing bad boolean names like status or flag.t fit, and the programmer is forced to chose more meaningful names.

Comment: @Gulzar the reason `locked` is better than `lock` is because the former is an adjective and the latter is a verb or noun. In English adjectives are used to represent state, such as "this door is locked" or "this engine is running".  

However if OP actually wants to "indicate the action" then an argument named `action`, whose value can be `'lock'` or `'unlock'`, would be appropriate. As it is, the boolean `isLocked` describes the target state of the action, not the action itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important is that the method name reflects a behavior. You do this perfectly well with the `Set` prefix (if your project indeed doesn’t use [lower camel case](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) for [method names](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5.2-specific-identifier-names)).

The consumers would then write something very unambiguous and self-documenting:

```
myobject.SetLock(true);
```

As a consumer, I perfectly understand that the parameter name in your interface definition reflects the intended target state that will result from the operation:

```
SetLock (boolean isLocked);
```

For the maintainers of this class, the name of the parameter will probably be understood the same way. You just should avoid any confusion with the internal state.
It is nevertheless true that the readability and clarify of the implementing code will have ups and downs:

```
internallyLocked = isLocked;     // rather clear
if (isLocked) { ... }            // rather ambiguous
```

If you want to improve that readability, the problem of your name is not so much the ending of your parameter but its beginning. In all objectivity:

- if the parameter starts with `is`, the end should be `lock`**`ed`** for the sake of grammatical consistency;
- `is` prefix suggests a current state when used in the method body. If you want to avoid any potential ambiguity, you could use a less ambiguous prefix to clarify the intention: either reflect a change of state, or a target state.

The exact choice of wording is opinion based. I could think for example of `toBeLocked` (target state clearly expressed) or `willLock` (change action clearly expressed). The latter has the advantage that it belongs to the [usual prefixes](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/34-better-boolean-variable-names/) (`is`, `has`, `can`, `will`, `was`, `did`) But there are certainly many other possibilities that comply with these basic principles.

Answer (score 0):

I recently brought to a discussion similar to this the analogy of a ceiling lamp.

Consider someone asks you to turn the lights off. What do you do?

1. Look at ceiling.
2. Is the lamp on?

   1. Press the switch on the wall.
3. Say done.

What you are asking is what action did I do with the switch?

- You could simply say you pressed it, and therefore the name `press` is ok as the method name.
- You could also say you toggled the state of the switch, and therefore the name `toggle` is ok as the method name.

Toggle, however, conveys a bit more information. Toggle associates with state, you toggle between two states. On and Off, in the case of the light bulb.

What you did not do, in the literall sense, was turning off the lamp. You toggled the switch to control the electricity that goes in to the lamp. *You could have pressed a switch for another lamp, for example.*

So you checked the state of the lamp to decide whether to press the switch. Therefore `state` is a concept of the lamp; `press` is concept of the switch; `toggle` is a concept of the ceiling lamp system.

In conclusion, different terms are appropriate in different contexts of a system. And the correct usage of terms in the correct context is what you are looking for.